# CSS position: camera.js overlapping drop-down menu

Tags: html, css

I have a project, that has a Camera.js slider. The Drop-down submenu is rather long, and it keeps appearing below the slider.

I have tried switching around the `position` for the `nav` element with `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, gave it  `z-index` of 99999, but still no change.

Can somebody help me out? I am out of ideas. The site is published here: http://www.xn--ftsszerels-c7ah27o.info/

Comment: you want the drop down menu (black background) to appear over the slider right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: did you try position:absolute, combined with z-index?

Comment: @ImAtWar Yes, already tried that.

Comment: cameraContents {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}container {
margin-bottom: 40px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

Comment: i believe you have the container at z-index, where as you have the camera contents also at the same index level.

Comment: @ImAtWar sorry, I do not really understand. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: Both the nav and the camera elements are inside the container. The position on the container does not add much to the strory. It is only the nav and the camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your camera_wrap class z-index: -1.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any positioning/z-index set on the div.container element so try setting `position:relative; z-index: (less than what is set on nav)`
i think that should do it

Comment: As I see problem comes from the Camera.js that puts code inside the #camera-wrap. As I browse throuhg the js file I see it uses a bunch of absolute positions with hell a lot of z-index values. I still don't get how z-index of 99999 on the nav with absolute position does not solve it.

Comment: any chance you can copy and paste all that into a fiddle to play with? i'll take another look now